# Does clearing the tower with a reconfigured palette advance the story?

Tags: splatoon-3, splatoon-3-side-order

After clearing the tower in Splatoon 3 Side Order for the first time, you are encouraged to clear it again with different palettes (weapon sets) to reconfigure them. Each time I've reached the top of the tower with a new palette, Smollusk has had new dialogue that has advanced the story.

What happens if I clear the tower with a reconfigured palette I've already cleared the tower with before? Will Smollusk have new dialogue to advance the story, or do you only get more story when clearing the tower with a new palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Smollusk's story will only advance when clearing the tower with a new Palette. If you clear it with an already re-configured comment, Smollusk will instead comment on how you've already beaten it with said palette.

[image]